# How to create hmac md5 in php?

Tags: php

I am working with payU credit card systems. But I dont manage.
payU tells me that I have to create hmac md5 hashes.

My secret key is : 3~9#[X4^660?ak+]h6%T
I want to convert to a HMAC_MD5 hash : 8GEMISEPE6208617192012-12-15 15:58:476Deneme117Deneme202103NET112242103TRY2107Antalya7Antalya2TR8CCVISAMC2,3,7,10,12

What's the php code?

Comment: The thing about "secret keys" is usually that you keep them a secret ;)

Comment: I hope you will take the necessary steps to avoid this question becoming a security vulnerability for your app!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Answer (score 20):

You can easily do that using the [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function:

```
$input = 'foo';
$output = hash_hmac('md5', $input, $secretKey);
```

where `$secretKey` holds a string representation of your key.

Comment: that didn't worked for me. the formula that they used is different from PHP hash_hmac conversion.. i wonder why...

Answer (score 2):

this php function class worked for me:

```
   function hmac ($key, $data)
              {
              // RFC 2104 HMAC implementation for php.
              // Creates an md5 HMAC.
              // Eliminates the need to install mhash to compute a HMAC
              // Hacked by Lance Rushing
              $b = 64; // byte length for md5
              if (strlen($key) > $b) {
              $key = pack("H*",md5($key));
              }
              $key = str_pad($key, $b, chr(0x00));
              $ipad = str_pad('', $b, chr(0x36));
              $opad = str_pad('', $b, chr(0x5c));
              $k_ipad = $key ^ $ipad ;
              $k_opad = $key ^ $opad;
              return md5($k_opad . pack("H*",md5($k_ipad . $data)));
              }


            $x_fp_hash = hmac($string1,$string2);
```